# Create a set of points that curve based on face normals

Tags: modeling, python, bezier-curves, object-mode, vector

I have 2 given locations to create a path between two points: the start and end points. I want to create a method in python that will give the points/vectors to create a curve between the two and use a third variable to control the direction of the curvature. In the image below, the direction can be defined using the face normals of the start and end points. *(The normal can also be given manually without using the faces).*

[image: Direction of curve indicated by green arrow]

The number of points between the initial two points can be controlled using the method. These points will then be used to create a curve object.

[image: Points are given to create the curvature]

Comment: Would you also be interested in a solution with *Geometry Nodes*, or does it have to be Python?

Comment: @quellenform It has to be python. Though a geometry node solution can be helpful to others.

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly based on the example given, but from the description it sounds like you want to create a bezier curve with control points along normals:

```py
import bpy
from bpy import context as C, data as D

strength = 5
num_points = 20

if C.mode != 'EDIT_MESH':
    raise Exception("Select two objects, go to Edit Mode and select a face for each")

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')

ob1, ob2 = C.selected_objects
f1, f2 = (f for ob in (ob1, ob2) for f in ob.data.polygons if f.select)
m1, m2 = (o.matrix_world for o in C.selected_objects)

curve_data = D.curves.new('connector', type='CURVE')
curve_data.dimensions = '3D'
curve_data.resolution_u = num_points
spline = curve_data.splines.new('BEZIER')
spline.bezier_points.add(1)
start, end = spline.bezier_points

start.handle_left = m1 @ f1.center
start.co = start.handle_left
start.handle_right = m1 @ (f1.center + f1.normal*strength)

end.handle_left = m2 @ (f2.center + f2.normal*strength)
end.co = m2 @ f2.center
end.handle_right = end.co

curve_ob = D.objects.new('connector', curve_data)
C.collection.objects.link(curve_ob)

# bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
```

[image]

You say you want to generate "a number of points", which you can do by converting the curve to the mesh, though I'm not sure if this is something you really need, as you say later you want to convert it to a curve anyway... You can add to the code:

```py
# Convert to a mesh:
ob1.select_set(False)
ob2.select_set(False)
C.view_layer.objects.active = curve_ob
curve_ob.select_set(True)
bpy.ops.object.convert(target='MESH')
```

### Mathematics

The maths are as simple as defining two lines and interpolating (lerping) between them, e.g. define a line going from the center of face1 towards its normal, and another line from the center of face2 towards its normal. Then just go away from face1 on each point, and towards face2 on each point on those lines, and interpolate between the results. This is pretty much what the quadratic bezier does, except in its formula both lines point to the same point which is defined by the control point, so it's just a matter of when you calculate the control point, but the result is the same. This quadratic bezier is similar to the example given by OP. For a cubic bezier, just interpolate between two quadratic beziers. For higher order beziers interpolate between lower order beziers...

```py
import bpy
from bpy import context as C, data as D

strength = 5
num_points = 20

if C.mode != 'EDIT_MESH':
    raise Exception("Select two objects, go to Edit Mode and select a face for each")

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')

ob1, ob2 = C.selected_objects
f1, f2 = (f for ob in (ob1, ob2) for f in ob.data.polygons if f.select)
m1, m2 = (o.matrix_world for o in C.selected_objects)

co1, n1 = f1.center, f1.normal * strength
co2, n2 = f2.center, f2.normal * strength

verts = []
edges = []
last_i = num_points - 1


def lerp_between_straight_lines(i):
    weight1 = i/last_i
    weight2 = (last_i - i)/last_i
    along_n1 = co1 + n1*weight2
    along_n2 = co2 + n2*weight1
    return along_n1 * weight1 + along_n2 * weight2
        

def quad_bezier(i):
    t = i/last_i  # same as weight1
    # weight2 became (1-t)
    co = (co1 + co2) / 2
    n = (n1 + n2) / 2
    control_point = co + n
    
    # again two straight lines, but this time not along normals but towards the control point
    from_co1_to_co = (1-t)*co1 + t*control_point
    from_co2_to_co = t*co2 + (1-t)*control_point
    return (1-t)*from_co1_to_co + t*from_co2_to_co


def cubic_bezier(i):
    t = i/last_i
    cp1 = co1 + n1
    cp2 = co2 + n2
    
    from_co1_to_cp1 = (1-t)*co1 + t*cp1
    from_cp2_to_cp1 = t*cp2 + (1-t)*cp1 
    quad_bezier_1 = (1-t)*from_co1_to_cp1 + t*from_cp2_to_cp1
    
    from_cp1_to_cp2 = (1-t)*cp1 + t*cp2
    from_co2_to_cp2 = t*co2 + (1-t)*cp2
    quad_bezier_2 = (1-t)*from_cp1_to_cp2 + t*from_co2_to_cp2
    
    return (1-t)*quad_bezier_1 + t*quad_bezier_2



for i in range(num_points):
    p = lerp_between_straight_lines(i)
#    p = quad_bezier(i)
#    p = cubic_bezier(i)
    verts.append(p.to_tuple())
    if i > 0:
        edges.append((i-1, i)) 
 

me = D.meshes.new('connector')
me.from_pydata(verts, edges, [])
ob = D.objects.new('connector', me)
C.collection.objects.link(ob)
```

Comment: +1 for using curves to simplify the code.

Comment: Marking the above answer as the accepted post. I was looking for a mathematical solution but ended up doing the same thing anyway. My version however uses a third point for the normal offset.

Comment: @Blenderguppy it's perfectly fine to add an answer to your own question to share your solution!